# Identify This Compressed Bytestream

Tags: c#, zip, gzip, zlib

I have a file format that was generated by an enterprise, legacy (10y+) C# application.  It almost certainly was compressed by some form of zlib, and was found in a zipped wrapper package much like .docx.  The files are generated and named `something.xmlzip`, but I have not found a way of decompressing the stream through zip/gzip-type tools, or by using python's deflate/gzip methods and trying to bypass the lack of any stream headers.  The contents are certainly an XML document.

The main identifying characteristics of the data are a consistent header/magic number and trailer:

`$ xxd thedoc | head -1
00000000: 0404 0a04 3ae4 706e 03c4 0585 3a1b 3a0c  ....:.pn....:.:.`

`$ xxd thedoc | tail -n 2
00003320: 1c0c 6d8d 6d7d 6458 0bfe 61d7 7a5d 7c38  ..m.m}dX..a.z]|8
00003330: 338b 2640 fffe fffe                      3.&@....`

The `0404 0a04` header and `fffe fffe` trailer appear in every file.  How might I inflate these files?

Comment: Hmm, Blowfish encryption maybe? I search my local [magic](https://linux.die.net/man/5/magic) file and seems `0404` and `0a04` are Blowfish and Twofish encryptions respectively. Also, `fffe` is a Unicode byte order mark apparently.

Comment: Nope, guess I was wrong. It's `FEFF` that's a byte order mark; `FFFE` is merely a ["Specials" codepoint.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)